# Reduce table records based on minimum time difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a log table (MS SQL SERVER) with event entries (events are user actions like "user logged in", "user viewed entity A" etc).

Some events like "user viewed entity A" may occur multiple times within a short time frame. For instance if a user goes back and forward in his browser he may enter entity A's page multiple times within a minute, and multiple "user view" events will be logged.

For my analytics dashboard I would like to count how many times a user viewed entity A, but I would like to "debounce" the result. I want to consider multiple "user view" events close to one another as one "user view" event. Specifically, I want to consider a new "user view" event only if it is more than 30 minutes from the last one.

So having a table like this (last column is my comments for clarity):

| timestamp | evt_type | user_id | entity_id | *time diff from previous event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15:30 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | NULL (first view) |
| 15:38 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | 8mins |
| 16:05 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | 28mins |
| 16:50 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | 45mins (this counts as new view) |
| 17:15 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | 25mins |
| 17:44 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | 29mins |
| 18:30 | ENTITY_VIEW | U1 | E1 | 46mins (this counts as another view) |

I would like to determine that the user "viewed" the entity 3 times.

What would be a query to determine this? I tried LEAD, LAG, PARTITION BY and other comnbinations but I don't seem to find the correct way as I am not an SQL expert.

Comment: How do you want to treat a long string of views, that is, if the user views a site every 10 minutes for 2 hours, does that resolve to 1 view, because only the first was not within 30 minutes of the previous, or 4, because every 30 minutes the band "resets"?

Comment: It's kind of a sliding expiration. If the user enters the page every 29 mins during the whole day, this counts as one visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be a simple `LAG()` to grab the previous timestamp and check the diff. Will say your column [timestamp] is an odd data type, what about different days? Is there a separate column for date?

### Return Records >30 Minutes from Previous Record

```
WITH cte_DeltaSinceLastView AS (
    SELECT *
        /*Grab previous record for each user_id/entity_id combo*/
        ,PrevTimestamp = LAG([timestamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id],[entity_id] ORDER BY [timestamp])
    FROM YourTable
    ) AS A(ID,[user_id],[entity_id],[timestamp])
)
SELECT *,MinutesSinceLastView = DATEDIFF(minute,PrevTimestamp,[Timestamp])
FROM cte_DeltaSinceLastView
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,PrevTimestamp,[timestamp]) > 30 /*Over 30 minutes between last view*/
OR PrevTimestamp IS NULL /*First view will not have previous timestamp to compare against*/
```

Comment: the table I presented is just for illustration purposes. I wanted to know the algorithm to solve my problem. The actual timestamp is datetimeoffset.

Your answer is probably the correct one. Funny thing it was that simple. I have completed far more complicated tasks in sql, but last night my mind was shut off of exhaustion :)

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try is a correlated subquery that disregards any rows that are within 30 minutes of previous rows, the remaining rows should be the ones that qualify (ie a gap of 30+ minutes exists). See if this works for you?

```
select Sum(vc) as ViewedCount
from (
    select case when exists (
      select * from t t2 
        where t2.timestamp > t.timestamp 
          and t2.evt_type = t.evt_type 
          and t2.user_id = t.user_id 
          and t2.entity_id = t.entity_id
          and DateDiff(minute, t.timestamp,t2.timestamp) <30 
      ) then 0 else 1 end vc
    from t
)b;
```

This assumes that *Timestamp* is a *time* data type. This won't work across day boundaries but the same concept should apply with a datetime type.

[Demo as Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b90d1f302dfcf27eacb462276411cbab)